# How to display cards in the same row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I want to display cards in the same row - 3 cards at once using mdbootsrap

you can view my site here:
abusive-secretary.surge.sh

the problem i have is that only 1 card shows on the page and i cant figure out how to display 3 cards at once.

I want to display card 1 card 2 card 3 and than they are supposed to change to card 4 card 5 card 6.

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center my-3">Bootstrap 4 Card Carousel</h1>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is
                a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center mt-4">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mx-1 prev" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Previous">
              <i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mx-1 next" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Next">
              <i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
  /* Tablet and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

/* Desktop and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand, you have now 3 cards but than you say carousell item1 carousell item 2? i dont understand

Comment: and if i just copy/paste your code the cards are underneath each other and not next to each other

Comment: This  is only a fragment so copy and paste wont work. And as I dont know your breakpoint class md might be to large

Comment: so why are you posting it than?

Comment: To give you an idea whats might work and not to write unpaid code for you

Comment: I have a working sample but its to large for here so can I upload it some where

Comment: post it on pastepin

Comment: no, i dont like it- i dont need no controllers and none of that stuff. I just want something siple as you can see on the top of this site https://www.dapp.com/.

Comment: i copied this code from here but for some reason its not working with mdbootstrap.
https://codepen.io/zso2u/pen/jKmmqB

Answer (score 0):

> **HTML Code**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Carousel Reviews</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-reviews broun-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="carousel-reviews" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                       <div class="col-lg-4">
                         <div class="card"> 
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <div class="card"> 
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="card-body">
                         <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <div class="card"> 
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="card-body">
                         <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="col-lg-4">
                         <div class="card"> 
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                             <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                         <div class="card"> 
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                           <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                         <div class="card"> 
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                             <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="col-lg-4">
                         <div class="card"> 
                          <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                          <div class="card-body">
                           <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <div class="card"> 
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <div class="card"> 
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="card-body">
                         <h4 class="card-title">bharti parmar</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">I am an architect and engineer</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-reviews" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-reviews" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **CSS Code**

```
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right  {background:none;width:25px;}
.carousel-control.left {left:-25px;}
.carousel-control.right {right:-25px;}
.broun-block {
    background: url("img.jpg") repeat scroll center top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    padding-bottom: 34px;
}
```